# Create a function for mean calculation using an specific rule

Tags: r, aggregate, apply, mean

I need to create a function for mean calculation using an specific rule without the use of `apply` or `aggregate` functions. I have 3 variables and I would like to calculate the mean of `var3` each change in `var2` first and second the var 3 mean each change in the `var1` in the same function. This is possible? My code is:

### Variable 1

```
var1 <- sort(rep(LETTERS[1:3],10))
```

### Variable 2

```
var2 <- rep(1:5,6)
```

### Variable 3

```
var3 <- rnorm(30)
```

### Create data frame

```
DB<-NULL
DB<-cbind(var1,var2,as.numeric(var3))
head(DB)
```

### Function for calculate the mean follow a rule

```
mymean <- function(x, db=DB){

for (1:length(db[,1])){

if (db[,[i]] != db[,[i]]) {
mean(db[,[i]])
}
else (db[,[i]] == db[,[i]]) {
stop("invalid rule") 
}}
```

## Here start the problems and doesn't work

Thanks
Alexandre

Comment: Can you please share a like for like output? What do you want to see as the result? Pls show that

Comment: It's a bit confusing from the question, make some working example of the output.

Comment: You are making all kinds of mistakes here.  First off, if you want to make a `data.frame` use the following code. `db <- data.frame(var1 = sort(rep(LETTERS[1:3],10)), var2=rep(1:5,6), var3=rnorm(30))`.  Currently the object you call a `data.frame` is actually a `matrix`, consequently, all elements in the matrix are coerced to be a `character` because column one is a `character` type, to see this enter `class(DB[,2])`.  This is one reason why you function is failing because you can't take a mean of a character.  Additionally, your indexing does not makes sense, db[,[i]] does not work in R.

Comment: Continuing from above, for more information on sub-setting see http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to obtain means by groups.

To do this I would use the `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)

db <- data.frame(var1 = sort(rep(LETTERS[1:3],10)), var2=rep(1:5,6), var3=rnorm(30))
db %>%
group_by(var1) %>%
summarise(mean_over_va1 = mean(var3))
  var1 mean_over_va1
1    A    0.07314416
2    B   -0.05983557
3    C   -0.03592565

db %>%
group_by(var2) %>%
summarise(mean_over_va2 = mean(var3))

  var2 mean_over_va2
 1    1 -0.4512942044
 2    2 -0.1331316802
 3    3  0.0821958902
 4    4 -0.0001081054
 5    5  0.4646429921
```

From you comments however, it appears that you don't want to use any base R commands like `apply` and `aggregate` so I assume you may not like the above solution.

If I had to do this with brute force do something like this:

```
db <- data.frame(var1 = sort(rep(LETTERS[1:3],10)), var2=rep(1:5,6), var3=rnorm(30), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Obtaining Groups
group1 <- unique(db$var1)
group2 <- unique(db$var2)

#Obtaining Number of Different types of groups so I dont have to keep calling length
N1 <- length(group1)
N2 <- length(group2)

#Preallocating, not necessary but a good habit
res1 <- data.frame(group = group1, mean = rep(NA, N1))
res2 <- data.frame(group = group2, mean = rep(NA, N2))


#Looping over the group members rather than each row of data.  I like this approach because it relies more heavily on sub-setting than it does on iteration, which is always a good idea in R.
for (i in seq(1, N1)){
  res1[i,"mean"] <- mean(db[db$var1%in%group1[i], "var3"])
}

for (i in seq(1, N2)){
  res2[i,"mean"] <- mean(db[db$var2%in%group2[i], "var3"])
}

res <- list(res1, res2)
```